# Need to sort filenames with numeric at Last shell script

Tags: shell

Have list of files in the directory as
My folder names are as follows,

```
ATA8/
MUTA11/
USCA12/
MIUATA3/
SCUATA4/
GLUATA1/
HGVOLA10/
MmATA2/
LUATA9/
OLUATA13/
TA14/
LUATA5/
ATA6/
LUA7/
```

Need to sort files as

```
GLUATA1
MmATA2
MIUATA3
TA14/
LUATA5/
ATA6/
LUA7
ATA8/
LUATA9
HGVOLA10
MUTA11/
USCA12/
```

Using shell script

Tried using

```
ls -d M* | grep -v _old  | sort -t "A" -V -k 2
```

But it is not working as there are Two A

Comment: Welcome  Gowtham Rajagopal. Your question is unclear. How do you identify your files or directories, or files and directories, maybe including all subdirectories? And how do you sort? How `grep` command and `_old` is related?

Comment: @DudiBoy those are the directory i need to pass the directory one by one in sorted order

Comment: U can ignore i tried now
sort -n -t "T" -k 2 but still the files are not getting sorted

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting solution with `sed` and `sort`:

```
 sed -r "s|^([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)/|\1 \2/|" input.1.txt |sort -n -k 2|sed "s| ||"
```

results in:

```
GLUATA1/
MmATA2/
MIUATA3/
SCUATA4/
LUATA5/
ATA6/
LUA7/
ATA8/
LUATA9/
HGVOLA10/
MUTA11/
USCA12/
OLUATA13/
TA14/
```

### Explanation

##### `sed -r "s|^([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)/|\1 \2/|" input.1.txt`

Produce: List separated text from numbers with

```
ATA 8/
MUTA 11/
USCA 12/
MIUATA 3/
SCUATA 4/
GLUATA 1/
HGVOLA 10/
MmATA 2/
LUATA 9/
OLUATA 13/
TA 14/
LUATA 5/
ATA 6/
LUA 7/
```

##### `sort -n -k 2`

Produce: List sorted by second field

```
GLUATA 1/
MmATA 2/
MIUATA 3/
SCUATA 4/
LUATA 5/
ATA 6/
LUA 7/
ATA 8/
LUATA 9/
HGVOLA 10/
MUTA 11/
USCA 12/
OLUATA 13/
TA 14/
```

##### `sed "s| ||"`

Produce: List removed   separator.

```
GLUATA1/
MmATA2/
MIUATA3/
SCUATA4/
LUATA5/
ATA6/
LUA7/
ATA8/
LUATA9/
HGVOLA10/
MUTA11/
USCA12/
OLUATA13/
TA14/
```

Comment: Will it retain the same folder names

Comment: Yes it will retain the same folder names.